# Postgres now() greater than itself

Tags: postgresql

I INSERT a data with `now()` in the `createdAt` column.

```
INSERT INTO spaces
(id, name, createdAt)
VALUES(8, 'James', 'now()');
```

And when I SELECT the data that `createdAt > {date that generated from now()}`, somehow that data still included in the result query.

```
select id, "createdAt" from spaces where "createdAt" > '2021-11-05 09:20:02.846+0000';
```

[image]

I check the microsecond precision and it is excatly the same. Why is it like that? How do I fix it?

**UPDATE:**

`createdAt` column spec when CREATE TABLE

```
CREATE TABLE spaces (
    ...
    "createdAt" timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    ...
);
```

Comment: `'now()'` is a character literal.

Comment: it should be `now()` instead of `'now()'`

Comment: that's not the case in dbeaver, it is still generated the current date

Comment: @alramdein so it means that executing the following query you get a timestamp? `SELECT 'now()';` :O

Comment: yes. just try it on the dbeaver. But bro, that's not the case. Look at the screenshot, the query and the result showing a weird result. That's what I'm asking.

Comment: @alramdein I know it is not the issue.. I just had a question myself :-D cheers

Comment: @alramdein btw, what is the data type of `createdAt`. Could you add the create table statement to the question?

Comment: I am pretty sure that the problem is dbeaver's display of the timestamp.   Normally timestamp has 6 numbers in the milliseconds, although trailing 0s get removed.  Try doing just `select now()` a few times in a row. If you always only see three numbers as milliseconds then dbeaver is definitely truncating (or possibly rounding) when displaying the value.  In which case you cannot be sure of the precision with which it is actually stored.  I don't use dbeaver BTW.

Comment: @JonathanWillcock The problem is, I create a code that SELECT the last `createdAt` value from certain batch (limit) result query. And then use it as condition in the next SELECT query. Which is it is not related to dbeaver anymore. But still the same date included in the result query. (BTW this batching query is purposed to optimize the query and resources)

Comment: With what precision do you get that timestamp?

Comment: I just select it with [Sequelize](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html) `findAll` without any precision configuration: 
`this.IndexModel.findAll({
      attributes: ['id', 'createdAt'],
      where: { createdAt: { [Op.gt]: date } },
      order: [['createdAt', 'ASC']],
      limit: this.batchSize,
      raw: true,
    });
`

Comment: @JonathanWillcock and the result is like this `2021-11-05T09:02:26.099Z`. Guess it only get 3 numbres for the precision?

Comment: Then that is almost certainly rounded/truncated.

Comment: A postgres timestamp has more than three precision

Answer (score 0):

By default Postgres creates a timestamp with a precision of 6 milliseconds. You can however alter this by specifying the precision in parentheses after the timestamp.  It seems that your problem has to do with the precision with which your system retrieves the data, which seems to be restricted to three.

The obvious solution here is to reduce the precision with which Postgres stores the data, always assuming that the lesser precision is ok for your purposes.  In your case:

```
alter table spaces alter column createdat type timestamp(3) with time zone
```

(You might need quotes around createdat if the name really is in camel case)

EDIT

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47752672/how-to-use-milliseconds-in-sequelize-standard-createdat-field) appears to confirm that sequelize only provides precision for datetime to three decimals for milliseconds. Again I do not use sequelize so cannot personally confirm. This is just one of the reasons why I hate all ORMs (without exception). The extra time spent learning how to correctly interface to the database of your choice is repaid many times over in  performance. I have a standard candidate test for example, which demonstrates that a thought out approach using optimal tools is 500 times faster than EntityFramework. The worst answer I ever received from a candidate at interview was "I know EF is slow, so I put the operations in a background thread".

I realise this sounds like a rant, but I strongly believe that learning how to optimally interact with a database rather than just taking the lazy ORM approach is massively worth the effort.

Comment: Rather than altering the table, how to SELECT the data with full precision of the timestamp?

Comment: Use different software

Comment: I've said it to you that it is also happened in my code which is have nothing to do with DBeaver anymore

Comment: Have you tried npgsql?

Comment: no I haven't, gonna check it